# EF Core 5 with TPT for IdentityUser

Tags: c#, .net-5, ef-core-5.0, table-per-type

I'm trying to setup a project with multiple IdentityUsers. With EF 5 Core (code first) it should be possible to use TPT (Table Per Type). But for some reason the entity is created in a single table.

This is my code:

```cs
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().ToTable("Teachers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
}

public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
}

public class Teacher : User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}

public class Student : User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Major { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `Add-Migration`, it then creates a migration where both the `Teacher` and `Student` properties are placed in the `AspNetUsers` table.

Shouldn't it create a separate table for `Student` and `Teacher` when using EF Core 5?

Comment: Don't you have to also create a table for the `User` type? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration

Comment: @ElMac For some reason that seems to work. For the `User` entity I added a `ToTable("Users");` line. I also added it as a `DbSet` like so: `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");`. Oddly enough it doesn't create table called `User`, but it get its default name: `AspNetUsers`. But I do see that the `Teacher` and `Student` tables have a FK relation to the `AspNetUsers` table. So it looks like this works.

Comment: When inheriting `IdentityDbContext`, make sure to call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` **first**, then do your customizations. Base methods defines and configures the identity entities, including corresponding table names (all these `AspNetXyz` tables). After base call you can specify different names fluently.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, I didn't know. When I move the `base.OnModelCreating(..)` to the top then I also don't need to explicitly tell EF Core to create a table for `User`. I'm fine the its default `AspNetUsers` table name.